# C++ with embedded javascript running cef communication

Tags: javascript, c++, ogre

I want to create a C++ exe that runs ogre graphics engine. Ogre will create a chromium embedded framework and display an index.html to the end user. The index.html will also run javascript that will update the browser window. However I do still need some kind of communication between the C++ and "embedded" javascript. This is because the exe will sit on top of a platform that loads a DLL that the C++ code loads and talks to via call backs. So this means the DLL will suddenly trigger an event (because the DLL talks to another remote process) that will be handled in c++ and the result sent by JSON (doesnt have to be JSON) to the javascript code. This also has to work in reverse. So the user can interact with the embedded browser which needs to send a message (probably but not necessarily JSON) to the C++ code to communicate with the dll.

I cant open up a port on the machine for communication between C++ and javascript otherwise Id just use javascripts built in HTTP support.

Is there an elegant way to do this? Considering the C++ and javascript are sharing the same process space (I assume) there is a simple way of achieving this?

Many thanks